# postgresql create database tutorial

Tags: postgresql

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-createdb.html) for creating a user in postgresql.

It lists some commands to run, but does not say within what context to run them. I tried running the command psql,which takes me to a prompt like the following...

```
postgres=#
```

Then when I enter the commands shown in the tutorial there, absolutely nothing happens at all. What am I missing here?Also, why does the postgress official documentation guide have such gigantic gaping holes in the information it provides?

Comment: Don't forget a semicolon at the end of each SQL command.

Comment: @user2182349 — They haven't written any SQL commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have skipped past the part of the documentation that describes the [conventions it uses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/notation.html):

> SQL commands are preceded by the prompt =>, and shell commands are preceded by the prompt $.

The page you link to says:

> ```
> $ createdb mydb
> ```

So you should run it at the **shell prompt** and not the **postgres prompt**. i.e. Don't run the command `psql` first.

It doesn't tell you to run `psql` until [the **next** page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-accessdb.html).